# Setting up Content Delivery Webserver Root Locations for Tridion

Tags: tridion

Problem Description:
Publishing JSP pages work with the following for broker.config.

```
<Publications DefaultRootLocation="/apps/tridion/wwwroot"  
              DefaultRootDataLocation="/apps/tridion/wwwroot/data">
```

Publication pages and directories (based on structure groups) will publish under the wwwroot directory.

I changed the root location for for pages to the following (no longer using "/apps/tridion/wwwroot").

```
<Publications 
    DefaultRootLocation="/apps/ekibemobile/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/MobileTermsConditions.war/basic" 
    DefaultRootDataLocation="/apps/ekibemobile/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/MobileTermsConditions.war/basic/data"
    >
```

Publishing now returns:

> ```
> A processing error occurred processing a transport package Could not deploy page
> ```
>
> [Page id=tcm:493-637128-64 Title=010. Privacy Policy],
>   IO error creating new page, No such file or directory, No such file or
>   directory, IO error creating new page, No such file or directory, No
>   such file or directory

I confirmed the required permission on the above folder on the Linux webserver. I also tried the following in the  node of broker.config

```
<Publication Id="493" 
       DocumentRoot="/apps/ekibemobile/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/MobileTermsConditions.war/basic" 
       DataRoot="/apps/ekibemobile/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/MobileTermsConditions.war"
/>
```

I get the same error with this config. Please suggest what I'm missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to make the changes on the deployer.config (cd_deployer_config.xml) on the Tridion Presentation Server.

Comment: For this question to be useful to others, it would be interesting to know why this was the accepted answer. Did editing the deployer config solve the problem? If so, what edits did you make?

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

1. Double check that the directories you've specified do exist.
2. Ensure that the user running the deployer process has access to write to the directory
3. Edit both the deployer and broker configs to enable debug logging. Restart everything and repeat your test, then check the logs.

Note that the locations you have specified *are* configured in the broker configuration, but the deployer process is the relevant one because it will instantiate a broker.

Comment: I had this same error and solved it by fixing the path in my cd_storage_conf file on the Deployer.